# Any DC-powered, fast water heaters,induction heaters?

Tags: dc, heat, coil, solar-energy, water

Does anybody know a DC water heater? I am looking for a coil type design, so I can place it at the bottom of the container and it will get evenly heated. I need this to be DC and I am going to power it by solar. Also ideally I would like for the tech to be under 20$. If this can heat up a liter of water in under 10 minutes that would be great, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Use mirrors to heat directly. Skip the inefficient electric middleman. Also, you ask for an DC induction heating element which does not make sense. Do not underestimate specific heat capacity of water. You need 7W just to heat up 1K over 10 minutes if you do not lose any heat to ambient. Use the solar cells to stir the water instead or something.

Comment: Yes, I know a DC water heater, there's one in my kettle. Actually we use it with AC because heaters don't care whether the electricity is DC or AC.

Comment: i think that you forgot to mention something ... technically, dipping your finger in a liter of cold water will heat up the water

Comment: @RahulVijayan:  [Simplest way to heat water with solar energy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_water_heating)

Comment: @JRE I am trying to make a product, so using the sun is not the best method here, I also am trying to make it boil water fast. I understand what you are trying to say and you are correct but I think in my instance using technology seems better.

Comment: @DKNguyen I wanted to use technology as I see that to be a better fit in what I am trying to do. Do you know of any good heating elements, preferably a coil type?

Comment: @user253751 Do you know what type of the heating element is inside of your kettle, I am kinda trying to build a solar-powered kettle pretty much but I don't know what heating element to use?

Comment: @RahulVijayan "*the sun is not the best method here*" Ummmm...you were the one asking for it to be solar powered to begin with which is why we are talking about the sun. Solar cells are horribly inefficient and water can absorb a lot of heat so if you want to use solar power to heat up the water you should do it directly.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am sorry I thought you meant to put the water in the sun and to heat it that way. I did not understand what you meant. I really need to find a good DC water heater that is like a coil. Since you cant recommend a product to me could you tell me what type of heater would be best on my occasion?

Comment: @RahulVijayan He's saying that if you just paint the water tank black, it will heat up more than if you use a solar panel and an electric heater.

Answer (score 2):

> If this can heat up a liter of water in under 10 minutes that would be great, but it is not necessary.

$$ P = \frac {m \times \Delta T \times SHC} t $$

where \$P\$ is power (W), \$m\$ is mass (kg), \$\Delta T\$ is the temperature rise (°C), \$SHC\$ is the specific heat capacity of water and t is time (s).

So boiling water from 20°C requires:

$$ P = \frac {1 \times 80 \times 4200} {600} = 560 \ \text W$$

You might find a low-power electric kettle to do the job.

> Any DC-powered, fast water heaters,induction heaters?

A resistive element doesn't care whether the supply is DC or AC. Speed is determined purely by heater power. They aren't "faster" or "slower". An induction heater will have losses and be less efficient than a heating element which is 100% efficient at turning electrical energy into thermal energy.

Comment: Do you know any good heating elements that can be powered by solar energy and If you do know them can you send a link to buy them or their name?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Seeking product recommendations is against site rules and will get your question closed.

Comment: Why? I just wanted to know what type of product to look for as I am not very knowledgeable l in this area.

Comment: could you just tell me what to look for as that's not a product recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You have just described an electric kettle.  They are cheap and readily available.

You haven't said anything about the voltage or current.  European ones are likely to run on around 220 to 250V, and require around 10A.

The heating element won't care if the supply is AC or DC.  But if the kettle has an automatic switch to turn it off when boiling, then this could fail rapidly if used on DC, as DC is much more prone to arcing when switched off.

Edit: As Solomon Slow points out in a comment, other kettles are available with lower power ratings.  2.3kW is a higher power than you need.

I have tried a 12V kettle, intended to plug into a car accessory socket.  At a maximum of 120W (10A), it was largely useless.  I have also used a 230V travel heater, whuch could be dropped into a jug of water.  That was more successful.

Comment: @Simon B I am trying to use the heating element inside of the electric kettle for my own use. Do you know what the heating element inside of the kettle is called and also do you know how to power it?

Comment: Thank you everyone you have been really helpful.

Comment: @RahulVijayan the element inside a kettle is just a "kettle element".  Most are 120V or 230V.  24V ones do also exist - they are used by truckers.

Comment: @Simon B could I use a range burner surface element and hook that up to a battery and use that to boil the water. T

Comment: @RahulVijayan maybe.  But I don't suppose they are designed to be immersed in water, if that's what you are thinking.  But so far, you haven't told us anything about the voltage and current your solar system is capable of providing.  Or why you don't just buy a kettle.